# URL aliases [node:language] repetition issue

Tags: 7, uri, path-aliases

I have an issue with URL aliases creation. I have set my configuration as following:

[image: See image]

The default path pattern above is the only one configured. Yet, when I create my content type instances and translate them, I get the following:

```
http://mysite.localhost:8082/en/search-form
http://mysite.localhost:8082/fr/fr/recherche-de-mots
http://mysite.localhost:8082/ab/ab/dfghdf
```

EN is the default language, but why do I get double `/fr/fr` and `/ab/ab`? These are the links created in the language link available under node contents.

**REM:** *Generate automatic URL alias* is set on all node content translations.

**Update**

Of course, I would like to avoid repetitions (this is my real question):

```
http://mysite.localhost:8082/en/search-form
http://mysite.localhost:8082/fr/recherche-de-mots
http://mysite.localhost:8082/ab/dfghdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because Drupal is using the language prefix to generate the language URLs, and you are using the [node:language] token in the path pattern. As consequence, the language prefix appears twice.
In the first case, as English is the default language, the prefix doesn't appear twice because [node:language] is replaced from an empty string.

Just use [node:title], instead of [node:language]/[node:title] as path pattern.

The reason for allowing the use of [node:language] is that the other method to generate language URLs is through a domain for a specific language. Suppose you set http://exemple.com has domain for the French language; with your path pattern, the URL alias would be something like http://exemple.com/fr/recherche-de-mots, which is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Ok, but then how do I get to have them only once for each link?

Comment: I tried to use [node:title], instead of [node:language]/[node:title] as path pattern, but it just removes one level of language in the path, meaning EN is now http://mysite.localhost:8082/search-form instead of http://mysite.localhost:8082/en/search-form

Comment: Ok, I found out there was no 'Path prefix language code' set for English (default Drupal install), I just had to add 'en' in Home > Administration > Configuration > Regional and language > Languages for English, and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's also the possibility to *rewrite the results* of your `path`-field, and select "**Use absolute link**" (not to be confused with the similar option under "rewrite as link").

It gave me the right result.